# SonarLint not listing in Intellij Plugins

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

[image]

I m trying to install SonarLint but its not listing in IntelliJ plugin folder.

Comment: I see it (IntelliJ 15). The SonarLint plugin is also available in JetBrains repository (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7973). Please add you IntelliJ version. Did you configure proxy?

Comment: Version 13 Ultimate. Licensed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimum required version of IntelliJ is 14.1, this is why you don't see it when you browse the repositories.